# Creating a CKAN Extension Error: No such command 'create'

Tags: python, ubuntu, ckan

I'm Creating a CKAN EXTENSION base in their official documentation.

> https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/theming/templates.html#creating-a-ckan-extension

When I'm in this step,

> *ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini create -t ckanext-example_theme*

I got this error.
*

> (default) root@ccgeo:/usr/lib/ckan/default/src# ckan -c
> /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini create -t ckanext-example_theme 2021-10-27
> 02:27:45,515 INFO  [ckan.cli] Using configuration file
> /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini 2021-10-27 02:27:45,515 INFO
> [ckan.config.environment] Loading static files from public 2021-10-27
> 02:27:45,544 INFO  [ckan.config.environment] Loading templates from
> /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates 2021-10-27 02:27:45,762
> INFO  [ckan.config.environment] Loading templates from
> /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates Usage: ckan [OPTIONS]
> COMMAND [ARGS]... Error: No such command 'create'. (default)
> root@ccgeo:/usr/lib/ckan/default/src#

- 

Comment: did you install ckan dev requirements? if not, activate the venv (`. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate`), then go to the ckan root directory ( ` cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan ` ) and install like `pip install -r dev-requirements.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in the docs, it should be
`ckan generate extension` as correct CLI command
or in your case:

`ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini generate extension -o *location-to-put-generated-template*`